# reinitialize javascript with pjax on back button

Tags: javascript, ajax, pjax

Below "done" callback works well when button is clicked. But with browser back button, done callback is not called again.

```
$.pjax({
        url: $this.attr("href"), 
        container: '#div-section', 
        push: true
}).done(function() {
        $object.init();                 
});
```

is there some another way to fire other javascripts on pjax end other than done ( as it does not work )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution but there can be I guess only one such handler in page -

```
$(document).on("ready pjax:success", function(){
        //initialize all javascripts here
});
```

**EDIT**

Above solution leads to dual bindings on pjax calls, once inside pjax:success followed by second time inside done event callback. To have bindings executed only one on back / forward  or on pjax , we can do as below. In this case , globalEventDirection can be used to conditionally bind inside pjax:success leaving init to done in case button was clicked. But with back and forward button, init will be done inside pjax:success

```
    globalEventDirection = undefined;
    $(document).on("pjax:popstate", function(event){
            globalEventDirection = event.direction;
        });

    $(document).on("pjax:success", function(event){
        if(globalEventDirection === "back" || globalEventDirection === "forward" ) {
            //reinitialize javascript                   
            globalEventDirection = undefined;
        }
    });
```